# What is the Preferred Method to having multiple websites share checkout sessions

Tags: magento

I have implemented many multi site implementations in the past, so I get how to set up the environment. What I haven't done, is set up multiple websites that can share the same cart session.

So if you are on site1.com and add something to your cart or are logged on, when you go to site2.com you are logged in and have the same items in your cart.

From what I read around the forums, well there isn't much about the best way to share session. But I do know that using the configuration to enable SID on the frontend will pass the session id if you transfer between sites. I figured this is all you need to have, but I see where people are saying that only stores can share checkout sessions and that stores can have their own domain.

I am thinking the best way to do this is to setup multiple websites not one website multiple stores and then just make sure when linking to the other site, I use proper magento url methods to build out the link and it will pass over the SID and the users session will be transferred over.

Is this the preferred way to do this? Is there anything I need to know in terms of configuration? Is there any negatives doing it this? Is there a better way?,

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to have such possibility only for logged customers then i propose to you to use `sales_flat_quote` table which is represented by `Mage::getModel('sales/quote')`.

With this model you can manage `cart` and focus only in passing customer identifier which would bring us to security subject... How would you pass customer identifier in secure way as SID isn't very secure.

Plus SEO doesn't like SID in URL from what i've heard.